# Promise to return the value instead of a Promise when called

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to access some DATA after some HTTP and WS Calls. I have my data ready and I want to access them. But instead of the Data I get back the promise itself.

```
const authenticationRequest = () => axios.post(authenticationUrl, {
  user: username, password
})
  .then((response) => response.data)
  .catch((error) => console.error(console.error('Error Response', error)));


const wsRequest = authenticationRequest().then(reqToken => {
  const webSocketRequest = new WebSocket(topicDataUrl);
  const firstMessage = {
    token: reqToken,
    stats: 2,
    sql: "SELECT * FROM cc_payments LIMIT 100",
    live: false
  };

  var messages = [];

  webSocketRequest.onopen = () => {
    webSocketRequest.send(JSON.stringify(firstMessage));
    webSocketRequest.onmessage = (streamEvent) => {
      of(streamEvent).pipe(
        map(event => JSON.parse(event.data)),
        filter(message => message.type === 'RECORD')
      ).subscribe(message => messages.push(message.data.value));
    };
  };
  return messages; // Here I get my array of Message
});

const data = wsRequest.then(res => res);
console.log(data, 'DATA'); // This returns a Promise<Pending>. with Promsie<value>: Array[100]
```

The problem:
How to return the actual DATA instead of the Promise? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data is in `res` in your `then`-callback.

Answer (score 0):

`wsRequest.then(...)` returns another Promise, so this is why you see `Promise<Pending>` in your console.

To get the result of the Promise, instead of

```
const data = wsRequest.then(res => res);
console.log(data, 'DATA');
```

you can use

```
const data = wsRequest.then(res => console.log(res, 'DATA'));
```

or, as an alternative, use the more modern `await` approach:

```
const data = await wsRequest;
console.log(data, 'DATA');
```

Comment: Well, I am sure I am doing something wrong here. `res` inside the `then` is just the array. When I print `data` though, I still get a promise.

Comment: This is what I get in the console:
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Array(100)

Comment: @DimitrisEfst as soon as you use Promises, you either need to access the resolved data **within** a `then` callback or use `await`, there is no way that `wsRequest.then(…)` will return something else than a Promise.

Comment: `res inside the then is just the array. When I print data though, I still get a promise.` Yes, that's exactly how it works :-) So you need to access the Promise's result within the `then(...)` or by using `await`.